# What is it called when C# overloads a Class name based on generics?

Tags: c#, generics

E.g. I saw the following code for the first time today.

```
public abstract class SimpleFilter<T>
{
    //blah
}

public abstract class SimpleFilter<TA, TB> : SimpleFilter<SimpleFilter<TA,TB>.Pair> {

    //blah
    public struct Pair
    {
     // blah
    }
}
```

So the classes have the same name, but different amounts / types of generic parameters?

What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two class names that differ only in their generic arity (number of type parameters) need have *no* relationship between them. Nothing special is implied or performed because they happen to share the same names (ignoring type parameters).

In IL, they end up with names like `` SimpleFilter`1 `` and `` SimpleFilter`2 ``  - different names, and the number at the end of the name is just part of the name (but happens to indicate how many type parameters they have)

However, in this case we have two classes that also have an inheritance relationship. There's nothing specific to generics worth noting here.

Comment: Sure, but does this language feature have a name?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach - *what* language feature? As I've tried to indicate, there's nothing special happening here. We have two classes, where one inherits from the other. It happens that if you ignore the arity part of their names, the names are the same, but *what of it*?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach It is **no** feature, the number of type parameters is part of the type's name, so they are different types. There is no name for a "feature" that `class A<T>` is a different type than `class B<T,V>`.

Comment: This isn't possible in some other languages, so yes I'd call it a feature of C#.

feature; noun; a distinctive attribute or aspect of something.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach - the only thing I can pull out of this is that you weren't aware that the arity is considered to be part of the name. But there's no specific name given to this aspect of naming things in C#.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach - that it's the arity specifically is why you cannot have `G<A,B>` and `G<C,D>` because both have 2 type parameters so the names are identical.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach I guess you could call the feature "CLR knows about generics"? In Java, JVM doesn't know about generics and all the type parameters are erased at runtime. That's why you can't do this in Java. But the CLR knows about generics so it can different these types.

Answer (score 4):

Methods with different signatures but the same name are called overloads. We collectively say "the overloads of a method" because most of the time the methods do the same thing. `String.Split(char[])` and `String.Split(char[], StringSplitOptions)` are essentially doing the same thing - splitting a string.

However, types with different numbers of generic type parameters are not like that. They represent totally different things. `Tuple<T1, T2>` represents a tuple with 2 values. `Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>` represents a tuple with 5 values. These are completely different things. We don't have a special name for that. We just call it `Tuple<T1, T2>` or `Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>`. They aren't really related to each other because they represent very different things.

Personally, I have never tried to collectively refer to all the different classes that has the same name. I guess you could call it "the `Tuple` classes", or in this case, "the `SimpleFilter` classes".

And this is not a language feature. Classes with the same name but different type parameters are just different classes. As far as the compiler is concerned, `Tuple<T1, T2>` and `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>` are different classes, just like `String` and `Stream` are different classes. Obviously we humans might not think the same way.